# Как инициализировать размер массива с использованием конструктора?

Tags: c++

Я хочу при вызове конструктора задать размер массива, находящегося в теле класса. Для этого я пытаюсь использовать указатель p, который бы забирал значение из конструктора. Я делаю это так:

```
class bigestint
{
    const int* p;

    long long int Body[*p];

    bigestint(const int R)
    {
        p = &R;

    }

};
```

Ошибка возникает здесь: "long long int Body[*p]". Я пробовал несколько раз добавлять слова const и static к определению p (Так как компилятор ругается на то, что это не const значение или нестатическая ссылка), но на самом деле не понимаю как работает static.

Подскажите как можно исправить/реализовать то что я хочу, и можно ли так делать в принципе. Спасибо.

Comment: Начнем с того, что вы хотите указать в качестве размера массива указатель... Далее - все же *размер класса* должен быть определен во время компиляции, так что вам следует в конструкторе выделять память для массива динамически, а в деструкторе - ее освобождать.

Comment: @Harry с указателям это я действительно загнул. Вы сказали, что "размер класса должен быть определен во время компиляции". Можно ли как нибудь обойти это ограничение? Я бы не хотел выделять память под массив, если существует альтернативное решение, так как отладка с выделенной памятью сложнее по сравнению с обычным массивом.

Comment: Если бы такое было возможно, то каждый обьект класса мог бы иметь разный размер. Представте что было бы... Ужас

Comment: Ну, разве что выделить заведомо большее, чем нужно, количество памяти...

Comment: Если Вы просто не хотите выполнять нудную работу, то ее можно переложить, например, на vector...

Answer (score 1):

Если хотите хранить в классе именно массив, то нужно указать размер этого массива во время опознания типа(во время компиляции). В конструкторе же вы можете лишь указать размер, который предположительно будет использоваться, а остальная часть нужна для запаса(мало ли что?...). Экземпляры класса должны иметь возможность выдачи информации о размерах и о начале и конце массива, а  также о количестве запаса(неиспользованных элементов). Пример:

```
template <size_t SIZE>
class bigestint
{   
    long long  Body[SIZE]{};
    size_t length; //используемый размер
public:
    bigestint(const size_t R) : length(R % (SIZE + 1)) {}
    bigestint() : bigestint(SIZE) {}
    //неиспользованное количество элементов массива
    size_t free_place() const { return SIZE - length; }
    //получение другого типа
    template<size_t sz>
    struct rebind {
        using other = bigestint<sz>;
    };
    size_t size() const { return length; }
    long long* begin()  { return Body; }
    long long* end()  { return &Body[length]; }
    long long &operator [](const size_t index)
    {
        //обработать случай выхода за пределы размера
        if (index >= length)
            throw  std::out_of_range("  ");
        return Body[index];
    }
    //...
};


int main() {
     //занимаем память на 10 элементов, но 
    bigestint<10> arr(8); //используем 8 из них

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.size(); ++i) {
        arr[i] = i;
        cout << arr[i] << ' ';
    }
    //теперь мне нужна и остальная часть массива
    cout <<"\n работа с неиспользованной частью массива\n";
    long long* p = arr.end();
    for (int j = 0; j < arr.free_place(); ++j) {        
        p += j;
        *p = long long(arr.size() + j);
        cout << *p << ' ';
    }
    //но потом, мне понадобился массив побольше(на 15 элементов)
    cout << "\nесли нам нужен массив побольше, переходим на другой тип\n";
    decltype(arr)::rebind<15>::other m; 
    for (int k = 0; k < m.size(); ++k) {
        m[k] = 10 * (long long(k) + 1);
        cout << m[k] << ' ';
    }               
    return 0;
}
```

Если не акцентировать внимание на то, что есть некоторые недостатки, класс вполне удовлетворят ваши намерения, а если нет, то и не нужно хранить массивы (тем более, что лучше занимать память в стеке на один указатель, чем на целый массив, может быть, очень большой длины). В общем случаи, лучше пользоваться  стандартными контейнерами и адаптерами контейнеров.

Comment: Спасибо, вам большое! Но не могли бы объяснить пару строк?
"bigestint(const size_t R) : length(R % (SIZE + 1)) {}"
- begestin() - конструктор класса, а что такое ':' ? и что означает  length()? разве это не переменная?
"size_t free_place() const { return SIZE - length; }" - Я не совсем понимаю смысл const в данном случаи.

Comment: если вы обратили внимание, то класс  имеет два поля _ массив  Body и  размер массива  length. В языке есть возможность инициализировать поля  в списке инициализаторов конструктора. Метка ':' и есть начало спика инициализации, после него до тела конструктора  приводите список конструкторов.  : а(k), b(n)  и т.д. {} что означает, что 'a' конструируется со значением 'k',   'b'  конструируется со значением 'n'... В данном случаи наш обьект, хранящий размер _ length конструируется со значением  R % (SIZE + 1), чтобы по любому это значение не было больше чем  SIZE .

Comment: Далее  length это имя переменной(обьекта), который должен создаваться, и если вы сами не указываете с каким значением создать обьект, то обьект будет содержать мусор, пока вы не выполните присваивание.  Для константных обьектов нельзя вызвать неконстантные методы, поэтому те методы, которые не модифицирует обьект, нужно объявлять константными, чтобы  вызвать и для константных обьектов. К тому же модификатор сразу дает понять, что метод только для чтения. Если все понятно, и вам удовлетворил ответ, нажмите на галочку. Если  ответ не понравился _ на  стрелочку  для указания на не полезность